# use WHILE loop for mysql_fetch_array function

Tags: php

I have funcion that return $index:

```
$index = mysql_fetch_array($res);
return ($index);
```

now, in my code, I'm calling to this function:
$userSch = get_user_details ( $_SESSION['userID']);

and I want to run WHILE loop on it:

```
while($index = mysql_fetch_array($userSch)) 
{}
```

is it possible? because I'm getting error all te time:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in C:\Program Files
```

what I want to know is if is it possible to do this: `$userSch = mysql_fetch_array($res);` and than this: `while($index = mysql_fetch_array($userSch))` ?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects the results of a query.Try `foreach()$userSche as $blah {}`

Comment: `mysql_fetch_X` call must be a follow-up to a `mysql_query` call, which takes it's return as parameter (the #resource)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to get data from your database try this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT UserID, UserEmail, UserPassword FROM user_table WHERE (UserEmail = '{$email}') AND (UserPassword = '{$pass}');";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connection, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $id = $row[0];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
        $this->init($id);
    }
```

Comment: chase, the parameter to mysqli_fetch_row should be the result of mysqli_query, not the query.

Comment: is it possible to do this: $userSch = mysql_fetch_array($res);  and than this: while($index = mysql_fetch_array($userSch))  ?

Comment: It looks like the person is trying to get data